# Dropping elements from a list in R

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list named RUNS in R, and each element of RUNS is a matrix composed of numeric data. One of the calculations used to generate the matrices returned "Inf" as a value due to a denominator rounding to zero. This is causing problems with some work that I am now doing, and I am trying to figure out a way to simply drop the elements of RUNS that have "Inf" anywhere in them. I have not gotten it to work. I am trying:

```
TEST <- subset(RUNS, "Inf" %nin% RUNS)
```

using the %in% command from the Hmisc package, but it doesn't seem to do what I need. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Explain what you need, post dput(RUNS), and clarify the reason for using the same name in the selection clause as the name of the data.frame/matrix. Do you have a column of that name? (The answer may just `RUNS[is.finite(RUNS)]`)

Comment: I cannot get dput(RUNS) right now, because I have a long process running on it, but this will simulate it. 'code' a <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(1/0, 3)), nrow = 3)
b <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(2, 3)), nrow = 3)    
c <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(3, 3)), nrow = 3)

RUNS <- list(a,b,c)     What I need it to return is the list given by b <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(2, 3)), nrow = 3)
c <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(3, 3)), nrow = 3)

RUNS <- list(b,c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(RUNS, function(x) all(is.finite(x)))
[[1]]
[1] FALSE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

> RUNS[ sapply(RUNS, function(x) all(is.finite(x))) ]
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    2

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    1    3
[3,]    1    3
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# dummy vector with inf values
x <- c(1,2,3,rep(1/0,4),5,7,8)

# drop inf values
x <- x[!is.infinite(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
TEST = lapply(RUNS, function(x) subset(x, is.finite(x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Not sure why, but I still keep getting 'method not implemented for type 'list' for is.finite.

Comment: Is `RUNS` a list of lists?